# location of one program corresponding to another c++

Tags: c++, windows, networking, process

I have two programs So if i have one program "local" on machine A and another "remote" on machine B how can program "local" find out whether they both are running on same machine or different machine in c++ under windows environment.

Comment: You need to give more info. How can they "know" about each other unless you've already established a method of communication (that surely can reveal if they're local or not)? Or do you just want to know "is my app running on this machine?"

Comment: actually i have explanied it in comment below what basically i need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send the IP address of "self" from "local" to "remote"? Or let "remote" send it's IP address to "local". Then compare with "its own" IP address. If they are the same, then must be the same machine [or the machine has multiple network cards connected to the same overall network].

Ask for some other machine specific ID, such as mac-address, hard disk ID, etc.

There are myriad of different methods that may or may not work, depending on what you are actually trying to do.

Edit based on comment:

If you want to check if the program is available on the same machine, you could use a "named pipe" or some other named IPC mechanism, and simply check if the named IPC is available on the local machine. If not, use remote machine mechanism (e.g. TCP/IP).

Comment: i am actually looking fro something like if i have two program sending data to each other then if one process is local to another they will use local ipc methods but if they are remotly located then tcp/ip. so how can i detect about the program and then use it to decide which method for communication to use

Comment: ok so basically according to your edit you mean i should run a named pipe on every program and then check if that is on same machine ..but my other programs dont know anything about the pipe .so i have to send something of pipe like name or id to check and how can i do that?

Comment: I mean that "named pipe" is your local comms. Obviously, the pipe is created by one side of the communication, and the other side tries to open the pipe. If the pipe doesn't exist, there is no "other end" on this machine. Typically, it would be the remote side that creates the pipe, and the local side tries to connect to it. But it's possible to do it the other way around, if you like.

Answer (score 0):

> i am actually looking fro something like if i have two program sending
>   data to each other then if one process is local to another they will
>   use local ipc methods but if they are remotly located then tcp/ip. so
>   how can i detect about the program and then use it to decide which
>   method for communication to use

Try local IPC methods first. If they don't work, switch to TCP/IP.

Comment: but cant i check first and then decide how to communicate. because i tried getpeername but it needs connection on the server side to be accepted so basically connection has started but i want to start the communication after finding out local or remote.